# Conversion failed when using nvarchar, but not varchar

Tags: sql-server

I've run into a situation where I'm getting an error if I run the same query on the same table, the difference being the column type. The query used is:

```
 SELECT [name] FROM [demo] WHERE [name] = 1111111
```

If the `name` column is `varchar(7)` then it runs no problem.

If the `name` column is `nvarchar(7)` then it gives an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'BBBBBBB' to data type int.

The error makes sense - I can see why the integer value can't be directly compared to the string value. I also realise that I can resolve it with a cast to a string for the condition.

However, what I'm not getting is why the behaviour is different for `nvarchar` and `varchar`. [This chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine) appears to suggest that they should have the same behaviour for type conversion.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I do not beliefe, that `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` would behave differently in this case... Please try to [create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce this issue... I'm pretty sure, that your observation has got a different explanation...

Comment: Are you 100% thats happening?  Can you provide a simple example where a value of [name] is not a number and `= 1111111` works?

Comment: no repro,can you provide a repro `create table #test
(
id int,
name varchar(7)
)

insert into #test
select 1,'1111'
union all
select 1,'aaaaa'

select * from #test where name=1111`

Comment: I would guess that what's missing here is something else that limits the result set - a `TOP` or `FETCH`, either as part of this query or hidden inside a view definition, if `demo` turns out to be a view rather than a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you using `nvarchar` column your query should look like:

```
SELECT [name] FROM [demo] WHERE [name] = N'1111111'
```

`N` at the begin of string to make sure that your string is unicode string (nvarchar)